# Laravel | Select quiz questions in random order and have the answers shown for each question

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am displaying all of the questions using a foreach, and also one for the answers.

They both have a question_id in common.

But how do I make my application know where the answers belong to, using two foreach loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us more details, please?
From the few information you gave I can only guess...

**#1: create a `Answer` model**

**#2: add in your `Question` model the relationship with the `Answer` model:**

```
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
```

**#3: getting all the questions with the answers randomly ordered:**

```
$questions = Questions::get();

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    // getting the answer of a specific question ordered by RAND
    $answers = $question->answers()->orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();

    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        // here your answer
    }
}
```

More info about Laravel relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

if you are displaying the questions in a random order, then create an array $random 
which will store the question_id after displaying the question.
Now, for displaying the answer, iterate through that $random array and display the answer whose question_id is equal to $random[$i]

```
foreach ($random as $ques_id)
    display the answer whose question_id is $ques_id
```